# invalid socket key, soket.io server and cocoa-websocket client

Tags: socket.io, asyncsocket

I got invalid socket key warning on the server when trying to hand shake. It's happened sometimes and not all the time.

The server is socket.io over node.js and the client is cocoa-websocket.

Any help about it?

Thanks.